# Django If statement with boolean fields not working

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm getting the boolean value from a queryset like this:

```
activo = Carros.objects.all().values_list('is_active', flat=True).filter(nombre='carro')
```

then my **if** statement is this:

```
if activo == True:
   raise forms.ValidationError('El Auto está activo')
```

even though the variable *'activo'* gets a *True* value it does not return the ValidationError.

What I did was to set a variable

```
a = True
```

and then add it in the if statement

```
if activo == True:
   raise forms.ValidationError('El Auto está activo')
```

And it works.

In the Python shell whenver I excute the query I see the result lik this

```
<QuerySet [True]>
```

I'm not sure what is the problem.

the *'is_active'* field in the model:

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
```

Note: DB is Postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `'use_pure': True` to database OPTIONS.
This forces mysql-connector-python to use pure python connection instead of C extension, where I believe the bug lives, see [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30469)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
        'USER': os.environ['MYSQL_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'use_pure': True,
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you can set this in the settings.py file

`'OPTIONS': {'use_pure': True }`

**Edit:**

Since your output is retuning a queryset you will need to check the value to ensure that it's true. you can do it like so

```
activo = <your query set>
print(activo[0])#should return True

if activo[0]:
   raise forms.ValidationError('El Auto está activo')
```

Comment: Feel free to try

Comment: if I use ' if activo: ' even though if is False it is giving me the ValidationError when it shouldn´t

Comment: That's not possible. This validation error will only be returned if the boolean is true. My guess is that activo is returning true when you are expecting a false. You can check this by adding a print line of `activo` before the if statement.

Comment: yes I get this <QuerySet [False]> I don´t know why the query retrieves the data like that instead of pure 'False' or 'True'

Comment: dang! totally forgot about that, thanks! it works now.